# Running a script that requires the DISPLAY=:1 command, as a service

Tags: ubuntu, bash, services, xfce

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with the Xfce desktop + VNC server to access it.

I have a script that launches and controls a GUI app. I can launch it from a shell with `DISPLAY=:1 /home/script.sh` and it executes my app in the GUI just fine.

However, I need it to run as a service, so that any time I close it or the app closes itself, `script.sh` restarts.

I tried to create services under `/lib/systemd/system/` or `/etc/systemd/system/` but it never launches. I suspect it's because I need to pass `DISPLAY=:1` to first render it into the GUI session of my VNC server.

I get the following when I try to start the service:

`[/etc/systemd/system/abc.service:5] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: "DISPLAY=:1 /home/script.sh`

How do I properly set it up as a service?

Comment: Try this: [*How to use variables in a systemd service file?*](https://serverfault.com/a/868388)

Comment: Does not seem to work 
Environment=DISPLAY=:1

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are set using one or more of the `*Environment*` directives in the service file. See the `systemd.exec(5)` man page for details.

Comment: These asterisks are confusing. Formatting mishap maybe?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: No. Multiple directives that all contain "Environment".